# ElectronStore not permitted to access config in home for snap with 'strict' confinement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am building an Electron app that just presents a web url in a BrowserWindow. I am using electron-builder to package the application as a .deb package and a Snap. .deb just works. But electron-store does not have permission access to config.json in the HOME directory when I build the snap using '**strict**' confinement.

Everything works fine when I use '**classic**' or '**devmode**' confinement.

I have tried clearing all npm caches, configStore files in $HOME/.config.

main.js asks calls `ElectronStore.set()` when resize and close events are emitted. That's when the error crops up.

corresponding **main.js** code

```js
mainWindow.on('close', function() {
    conf.set('windowBounds', mainWindow.getBounds())
    conf.set("lastLink", mainWindow.webContents.getURL())
  })
```

**build** instructions for *electron-builder* in **package.json**

```
"build": {
    "appId": "org.anuj.${name}",
    "asar": true,
    "copyright": "MIT ©2019 Anuj Datar",
    "linux": {
      "category": "Notes;Office;Productivity",
      "packageCategory": "Notes;Office;Productivity",
      "description": "OneNote Desktop Client for Linux",
      "synopsis": "OneNote Desktop Client",
      "icon": "./src/images/icon.icns",
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "AppImage",
        "snap"
      ],
      "maintainer": "Anuj Datar <anuj.datar@gmail.com>",
      "artifactName": "${name}-${version}-${arch}.${ext}"
    },
    "deb": {
      "depends": [
        "gconf2",
        "gconf-service",
        "libnotify4",
        "libappindicator1",
        "libxtst6",
        "libnss3"
      ]
    },
    "snap": {
      "confinement": "strict",
      "grade": "stable"
    },
    "appImage": {
      "license": "LICENSE.md"
    }
  }
}
```

Window size and last link visited is supposed to stored in config, so session can be resumed when app is launched next time. Instead nothing is saved and I get the following error message:

**A JavaScript error occurred in the main process**

Uncaught Exception:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chown
>   '/home/anuj/snap/onenote-desktop/x1/.config/OneNote/config.json.1014786569'
>
> - at Object.chownSync (fs.js:1142:3)
> - at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/snap/onenote-desktop/x1/resources/app.asar/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:196:27)
> - at ElectronStore.set store [as store] (/snap/onenote-desktop/x1/resources/app.asar/node_modules/conf/index.js:227:19)
> - at ElectronStore.set store (/snap/onenote-desktop/x1/resources/app.asar/node_modules/conf/index.js:152:14)
> - at BrowseWindow.`<anonymous>` (/snap/onenote-desktop/x1/resources/app.asar/src/main.js:44:10)
> - at BrowserWindow.emit (events.js:194:13)

Here's the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/anujdatar/onenote-desktop/issues/7)